# Interface builder add only bottom border to TextField element

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Is there a possibility to add only one shadow to the text field element in the interface builder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Just add UIView with 1px height and fill it with whatever color you like.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Comment: coool nice tip at all